# Where can I see the az of my task in ecs in the MC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

The only place, where I see in which it, is in the management console in the target group, but actually I would like to see it somewhere in ecs.

Where can I see that, I only found the subnet so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never directly assign a specific AZ or list of AZs to ECS tasks. You assign a list of subnets. You can see the subnet the task is deployed to in the Task detail page (In the UI that is Cluster -> Tasks Tab -> Click the Task ID). From the task details page, you would click the subnet ID, which takes you to the subnet details page, and the AZ is listed there.